# How to prevent users from entering contact information (emails/phone numbers) in text inputs?

Tags: php, ios, regex, validation, email

I am working on an app that will eventually allow users to connect with each other, but first a user will be able to post some public information and I want to block them from posting contact information (mainly email and phone numbers).

Is there an algorithm or approach for iOS or PHP that can detect such information? (Note - This is not a simple regular expression. I want to prevent common "tricky" ways of users displaying their contact info to the public).

**Examples of what I want to block:**

- Call me at 123-123-1234
- Call me at one-two-three onetwothree one two three four
- Email me johnsmith@gmail.com
- Message me john smith at g mail dot com

Obviously, there are unlimited derivations of the above examples and others, so I can't just create a "quick" expression matching algorithm for them all.

I know there probably isn't a 100% perfect approach for this, but was curious if there was something out there that would be better than making my own from scratch.

Comment: So after you blocked the “common” forms of showing contact information, users will go find the “uncommon” ones … To solve this, you will either need AI, or HI (H=human, meaning active review of posted content before it gets published).

Comment: You can get close, dont listen to the above comments, you just have to be willing to make all the rules. Ill post a few of them below.

Comment: not saying its a good idea, all im saying is it's somewhat possible

Answer (score 4):

For email I always use this regex

```
 ("([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)")
```

for other emails, instead of using regex use string searches

```
if line.tolower.contains("dot") and line.tolower.contains("com")
or if line.tolower.contains("@") and "com"
or if line.tolower.contains("@") and "net"
or if line.tolower.contains("mail") and "com"
or if line.tolower.contains("gmail") or "Yahoo" or "hotmail" or "bing"
```

As you can see, you are going to have to make quite a few rules

For Phone Numbers

```
("(?:\b\d{10,11}\b)")
("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
```

Then like the emails, you will have to use .Contains

The only way to make sure you cover every number out there - you will need to add every area code in letter form in a series like:

```
"twosixfive"
"fourninesix"
```

as well as:

```
"two six five"
"four nine six"
```

as well as:

```
"two-six-five"
"four-nine-six"
```

here is a list of all the area codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NANP_area_codes

There's not that many, you just have to be willing to take the time to do it.

Comment: Im just saying. If he's set on doing this, he could do it, he would have to make a crap ton of rules, and it would take awhile for the messages to post - but to say it's impossible is inaccurate.